# Two different titles of Noragami manga, which one should I start?

Tags: noragami

I have seen only the anime. I heard that the manga is still ongoing and that Fujisaka was exposed in it but I was in dilemma when I saw two mangas: one with the name ***Shuuishuu***.

They are both still ongoing and seem original. Which one should I start?

Comment: Can you mention what their titles are? Or does the two of them have the exact same title? Also you might want to check the author's name and compare it to wikipedia or wikia.

Comment: Yeah i did Ayase Eri.. Apparently they're from the same authors.....

Answer (score 2):

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noragami#Manga)

> Extra chapters of [Noragami]... have been compiled into one volume under the title *Noragami Shūishū* (ノラガミ拾遺集). Both the main series and spin-off series have been licensed in North America by Kodansha Comics USA, under the title *Noragami: Stray God* and *Noragami: Stray Stories* respectively.

*Noragami: Stray God* (or simply *Noragami*) is the main series. *Noragami: Stray Stories* is a spinoff from the same author, Adachitoka.